# Basic insert into SQL

Tags: php, sql

I know this is really simple i haven't touched PHP and SQL in a few years.

This works

> $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `sonyCES2013`.`registration` (`id`,
>   `firstName`, `lastName`, `eMail`, `telephone`, `outlet`, `comfirm`,
>   `preferTime`, `date`) VALUES (NULL,`Cat`, 'Catherine',
>   'Cat@gmail.com', '123-456-4561', 'Some Text', 'Yes', '4:00pm'
>   ,'1/09/14')");

this doesn't work

> $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `sonyCES2013`.`registration`          (`id`,
>   `firstName`, `lastName`, `eMail`, `telephone`, `outlet`, `comfirm`,
>   `preferTime`, `date`)         VALUES
>   (NULL,`{$fName}`,`{$lName}`,`{$eMail}`,`{$telephone}`,`{$outlet}`,`{$comfirmation}`,`{
>   $preferTime}`,`{$day}`)");

help and yes i did check that the variables aren't empty and i did try without the `` between each {}

Comment: Always use bind variables.

Comment: You need to add quotes.

Comment: you need to add quotes around the strings... `'{$fname}', ...` but it looks like you're really opening yourself up for sql injection

Comment: When in doubt, print out your SQL statement, much easier to read that way.  But as gloomy said, you need to look up SQL injection.

Comment: That is a really great tip to print out the statement and compare it to the one phpAdmin generates. I did validate all my queries with regex, i guess that wont be enough. I wlll look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add ' '  to the variables to make the interpeter able to understand what you are trying to do ( in this case passing some php variable as parameters)

Use this and see if it works:

```
 $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO sonyCES2013.registration (id, firstName, lastName, 
                 eMail, telephone, outlet, comfirm, preferTime, date) VALUES
               (NULL,'$fName','$lName','$eMail','$telephone','$outlet',
                '$comfirmation','$preferTime','$day')");
```

Answer (score 1):

It won't work that way because the resulting SQL looks something like this:

```
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO sonyCES2013.registration (id, firstName, lastName, eMail, telephone, outlet, comfirm, preferTime, date) VALUES (NULL,Cat, Catherine, Cat@gmail.com, 123-456-4561, Some Text, Yes, 4:00pm ,1/09/14)");
```

Note the lack of single quotes around the strings, which make the SQL invalid.